# Where to store\update tnsnames.ora file when installed oracle client only?

Tags: connection, database

I installed the oracle client only but was told to update my tnsnames.ora file with the info my dba sent me.  But I don't have a tnsnames.ora file.

On another machine with a full oracle admin install it is at:

- C:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

So do I need the tnsnames.ora file?

How do I let oracle know where it is?

fk

Answer (score 4):

I have Oracle Client installed on my machine. Last week my DBA updated my "tnsnames.ora" file because of server change. The file is in:

- C:\oracle\ora81\network\ADMIN

I guess you should consult your DBA if copying the file to that directory doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

When you say oracle client only, are you using the Oracle Instant Client? If so you should set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to point to where ever you store your tnsnames.ora file

Answer (score 1):

Its in `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin` folder where  `%ORACLE_HOME%` is the parth to which the client is installed, and an entry is done to the PATH variable. If the file does not exist, create one, using the file on the other machine as a template

Answer (score 1):

On Yosemite (`10.10.3`) with `Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.1.19` the default place where the client looks for the file is `/etc`.

In theory you can override that by setting the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to the folder containing your `tnsnames.ora` file, but I had trouble doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If the .\network\admin folder exists on your machine, simply copy the tnsnames.ora in this directory.